# Google cloud vision with Google storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, ocr, vision-api

I am making a text detection application, using google vision api.

I want to figure out the way for a OCR detection function be able to load the jpg file.

This is a code referance I get from [google codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-vision-api-python#7), but when try to open the `url= gs://`    like the diagram demonstartes, the error message saying **invalid arguments**. I wonder if I have **missed anything??**

[image]

Then, i found out that, when it is deployed on cloud functions, google vision will **load image from storage**. but **HOW?**  I can not find any relenvant documents giving a detailed process about this. I am new to the code and bad at finding these instructions. Does anyone knows how can I successfuly reads/connect to the jpg file? or maybe provide a reference link regarding this? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Please don't upload code as image but as text. This will help others to test your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code on my end is running fine and appears to be correct, I just copied the code and run it through Google Cloud Shell, Be sure to install the Vision API python client library in your cloud shell: `pip install --upgrade google-cloud-vision`  If your intention is to open the the image you can access the image sample provided in the reference you mentioned here: https://storage.cloud.google.com/cloud-samples-data/vision/text/screen.jpg the uri provided in the code is the resource location of the image that is stored in Google Cloud Storage, the link above is the url equivalent of it .

Output:
[image]

I would suggest reading through official documents for more information about  the API using client libraries [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detect-labels-image-client-libraries) and although different implementation you can view this OCR usage [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr).

Comment: thx , it works out well on the shell, cause i done it on vscode, did not consider it may be a slightly different whe it is doing on the cloud. you pointed out my blindness

Comment: I've notice that you execute the .py file. I wonder where do you save the sampleSep1.py. For me, I just executed straight on shell>ipython

Comment: This is within the Google Cloud Shell directory. You can upload/download files from there by clicking the triple dot icon, Or by opening the ```Open Editor```.